# onetoonemapping in jpa with foerign key present in child table

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

[image]

[image]

i want to have a one to one relationship in jpa,where i will save parent price and child price should automatically get saved.my ID in parent price is generated by sequence.can somebody help me with the entity class.i don't have any foreign key refence in parent table(parent_price)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use @JoinColumn to tell JPA that it should us the FK on the CHILD_PRICING table.

For example

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="ID")
private ChildPricing childPricing;
```

Comment: Foreign key is not present in the parent table

Answer (score 0):

Try with PrimaryKeyJoinColumn :

```
@Entity
public class ChildPricing {
  @OneToOne
  @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
  private ParentPrice parentPrice;

  private String priceName;
}
```